# Dynamic library cause crash at runtime (Windows)

Tags: c, dll, crash

I'm currently trying to create a dynamic library (just a test to see how it works) and so far I've been able to create a .dll file and link it to another .c file but when I'm running my program nothing is shown on the terminal (even if there is a printf() before a call to the library function)

Here are the files for the dll :

```
test.h
-----------------
#pragma once
void foo();

test.c
-----------------
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

void foo() {
    printf("LOLOLOLO\n");
}
```

That I've compiled with :

```
gcc test.c -c -o test.o
gcc test.o -fPIC -shared -o libtest.dll
```

My main .c file which import my dll (that I won't rewrite it here because it does nothing except call foo in main with just a printf before and after foo to check that everything is doing fine)  compile with no errors nor warnings because I added the -L... and -I... necessary (and -ltest).
So I don't understand why it does not run.

Thanks in advance for the answers !

Edit : I just want to precise that if I export my library statically, it works perfectly

Edit2 : Here is the main program using foo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

int main() {
    printf("start\n");
    foo();

    printf("end\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you running under windows or Linux/bsd?

Comment: @CraigEstey I'm running on windows

Comment: `"even if there is a printf() before a call to the library function"` -- It may be helpful if you showed us a [mre] of the code which is calling the library function.

Comment: What toolchain/env are you using (e.g. cygwin, mingw)? Although, `.dll` is the normal windows extension for a shared library, my concern is that depending upon the toolchain/env, you may need to use `.so` as the extension.

Comment: @CraigEstey I'm using mingw64. 
I tried creating a .so file, the compiler does not even recognize it as a library ("-ltest: No such file or directory").

Comment: I can't say for sure about windows, but, for linux: If you _need_ `-fPIC`, you need it on the command that creates the `.o` [not the linker command]. Try: `gcc test.c -c -o test.o -fPIC ; gcc test.o -shared -o libtest.dll`

Comment: @CraigEstey Unfortunately, it does not work neither...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution.

I didn't know that it was NECESSARY on windows (because all the tutorials are on linux) to use the command `__declspec(dllexport)` for the library to works.

I hope it'll help someone in the future !